# How to access a go struct whilst only being given one property of it?

Tags: go, struct, properties

So lets say you have one property of a struct. You also know the name of the struct type, but there is a specific struct created called StructAccess you want to target. You know the id, but only that property, and none others. How would you get the other values of StructAccess with only the value of id (StructAccess.ID)

Just Asking.

Comment: There is not a solution to the problem given the information provided.  Do you have a slice or should me other collection of the struct values?

Answer (score 2):

> How would you get the other values of StructAccess with only the value of id (StructAccess.ID)

Not at all. This is impossible.